Did the DC Circuit court "blatantly disregard" a Supreme Court ruling on Guantanamo detainees for [at least] 5 years?
A 2013 piece by the Center for American Progress claims that

Since 2008, the [DC] circuit court has blatantly disregarded a U.S. Supreme Court ruling on the right to habeas corpus rights for Guantanamo Bay detainees and ignored the requirement that the circuit conduct a robust review of prisoners’ detainment.

Is this hyperbole, or did the DC Circuit really ignore a SCOTUS ruling for [at least] ~5 years?

Might be a better question on Law.SE, where they can provide legal opinions on whether the law has been ignored or not.

@Oddthinking: maybe, but I'm not sure. The fairly strong terms in which the source makes the claim makes it sound like it's an obvious fact, not a lawyerly dispute about how something was interpreted in the details.

But apparently nobody here has sufficient knowledge to answer the question.  I bet you'll get at least three answers within a day of posting at Law.SE, at least two of which will be a balanced analysis of how reasonable it is -- or isn't -- to use the word "ignored" here.
